# History.js, bookmarking and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, history.js, single-page-application

When using history js and bookmarking a single page application. How do I make the index page get returned when using these non-existing pages (as I only have one "real" page which is the index page)? One option is to make many controllers which all return the index page. But that seems like a bad solution. What I want is for the index page to be returned on whatever I write (with the web brower url kept the same).

Or how should I solve this problem?